# TRUNC function causes no records returned with BETWEEN and FULL data and time - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   audit_log 
WHERE  Trunc(query_date) BETWEEN To_date('12-DEC-2013 01:00:00 pm', 
                                 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') AND To_date( 
                                        '12-DEC-2013 02:00:00 pm', 
                                        'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

Although the time range contains data, for some reason, the query does not return any record.
I have check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369222/oracle-date-between-query) and I think I am following the advise by using 'To_date' function.

However, when I removed the function 'TRUNC' the query works perfectly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   audit_log 
WHERE  query_date BETWEEN To_date('12-DEC-2013 01:00:00 pm', 
                          'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') AND To_date( 
                                 '12-DEC-2013 02:00:00 pm', 
                                 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

I understand that 'TRUNC' returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. But Why using this function with FULL date and time does not return records? I assume it does not truncate any value and hence its existence like non existence. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The [`trunc()` function documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm) states that: "If you omit fmt, then the default format model 'DD' is used and the value returned is date truncated to the day with a time of midnight."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the TRUNC function without the second *format* parameter. Therefore, Oracle truncates your date to a full day, thus setting the time part to 0:00:00 am.

Your WHERE conditions however selects for a time between 1 and 2 pm, which none of the truncated dates fulfills.

Comment: Are saying that TRUNC truncate the date to full day regardless the time format sat ?

Comment: @hawk - `truc` truncates using the format paramater passed to the function (or `DD` by default). The date that is passed in does not inherently have any format; maybe you're confusimg how the date is displayed with how it's stored? The display format has no relevance to the function.

Comment: Yes, it cares about the second parameter (if provided), not about the date format specified in your session.

Answer (score 2):

using `Trunc(query_date)` will result into `12-DEC-2013 00:00:00 am` i.e. midnight, but in your query you have provided range between 1 pm and 2pm an that doesn't lie in the given range.