how is Time formatting done in a Java 8 vs 17 app
I am noticing an interesting case. Old app is in java 8 and uses javax.ws.rs for rest apis. New app is in Java 17 and uses Spring Boot. Rest all is unchanged. We have a variable in a class of java util Date type say receivedDate. Now when we send say "25-01-2017" from postman, in old app it comes as wed Jan 25 00:00:00.0 IST 2017 in old but in new it comes as wed Jan 25 05:30:00.0 IST 2017
    public class SampleClass {
        Integer num1;
        Date receivedDate;
        //getters and setters
    }

in Spring Boot rest controller, we do
public ResponseEntity getDetails(@RequestBody SampleClass sampleClass) {
     try {
        System.out.println("Execution of getDetails started. received date is: "+sampleClass.getReceivedDate());
...............}
....
}


Who converts the input 25-01-2017 to the Date representation in Java.
I want to know why is it taking the Indian Standard Time in new app into the account with 05:30 hrs being ahead of the Mean time.
Also I wanted it as in the old app.


Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Since the snippet seems to just print a Date then Spring, Rest, etc seems not needed.

Can you change the receivedDate type to be java.time.LocalDate?

As the comment by @k314159 suggests, neither in Java 8 nor in Java 17 should you use Date. You might consider using it in Java 1.4 and earlier. Throw it out and use LocalDate from java.time, the modern Java date and time API for a date. And at the same time get rid of your time zone problem.

You’ve not given enough info to answer directly. But here are some pointers.
java.util.Date#toString tells a lie
The toString method of Date tells a lie. While generating text to report the UTC value of the moment within the object, that method applies the JVM’s current default time zone. This creates the illusion of a time zone where actually the value has an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC.
That class has a terrible name. It does not represent a date. It represents a moment, a point on the timeline, a date with time of day as seen from an offset of zero.
Solution: Stop using that class.
public class SampleClass 
{
    Integer id ;
    java.time.LocalDate received ; 
    …
}

Avoid legacy date-time classes
You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
java.time.LocalDate

when we send say "25-01-2017"

Parse as a java.time.LocalDate.
Define a custom formatting pattern to match your input.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;

Parse.
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse( "25-01-2017" , f ) ;

No time of day is involved. Your problem is eliminated.

The format is always the same. When you concatenate a Date to a String the method Date.toString() is used to convert the date:

Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy


The difference is probably because the first date is not containing time information. Why is that we don't know because there are no details in the question of how sampleClass has been constructed or if there is a difference in the versions of other libraries.

Thanks for your insights, it really helped me to know unknown things. As I experimented, I came to know that my both Old and New apps, if we do Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("date is--- "+date);  We get the same result i.e. date is--- Wed May 15 09:40:45 IST 2024  . Now I think the mechanism which converts/maps the incoming field to Date field is responsible due to which in old app, it came with 00:00:00.0 timestamp and in new it came with 05:30:00.0. So is there any way we can have the mapping with 00 as timestamp.

In spring boot rest controller
how is a Date field mapped. Let us say we send in json {"receivedDate":"2024-05-15"} How will it be mapped to a field in Java object having a property private Date receivedDate; (assuming java.util.Date)

You should make a separate question for that. Or search first if there is an existing one.

In order to have consistent date handling between your old and new apps you can set default timezone in SB:
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}

And config jackson for formating:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public class SampleClass {
    private Integer bnaPicCareInfoId;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date receivedDate;
}

And update your app.properties
spring.jackson.date-format=dd-MM-yyyy
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC

By doing this dates are parsed and formatted consistently, aligning with the behavior of your old application.

Hello, your solution works properly. But I have one more issue, I do not want my whole app to follow the zone set by TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Can we do this for only one particular class or field property?
My actual issue is this as given by this stackoverflow question and answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966282/trunc-function-causes-no-records-returned-with-between-and-full-data-and-time). So in the old app, it used UTC time zone and used to give 00:00:00.0 but the new one gives 05:30:00.0 as the timestamp.

Setting the default time zone affects the entire JVM, so all of your program to the extend that it relies on the default time zone and also any other programs running in the same JVM. So it’s a bad idea.

Hi @Anonymous could you please elaborate. Should I not use  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

@AlokKumar I strongly recommend that you write your code in a way that is independent of the JVM’s default time zone since the default can be changed from any part of your program and from any other program in the JVM at any time without notice. So relying on it is fragile. And when you don’t rely on it, you also don’t need to set it. To answer your question: You should not use the poorly designed and outdated TimeZone class and also not its setDefault method.

Hello @Anonymous, thank you for your feedback. You're right, setting the default timezone globally can impact the entire JVM, which is not ideal. It's better to configure the timezone for specific fields or classes to avoid unintended side effects and ensure the application remains robust and maintainable. Thanks for pointing this out!
