# Select Query using SYSDATE

Tags: sql

The Employee table has four fields EmpNo,EmpName,FromDate and ToDate filelds. I have to select the EmpNo and EmpName where today’s date is between the from date and the to date.

```
Select EmpNo,EmpName from Employee where FromDate = Trunc(SYSDATE) And ToDate =Trunc(SYSDATE)
```

Is that the way of doing

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if current date is between two dates Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398632/check-if-current-date-is-between-two-dates-oracle-sql)

Comment: it is SQL database not Oracle

Comment: Oracle **is** using SQL. So your last comment doesn't make sense. If you are not using Oracle, then you *have* to tell us which DBMS you are actually using? ("SQL" is **not** a DBMS product, it's a query language used by all relational databases)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select EmpNo,EmpName from Employee where Trunc(SYSDATE) between FromDate And ToDate
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. What you're testing now is if `FromDate = ToDate = Trunc(SYSDATE)`, that is if `Trunc(SYSDATE)` equals both the other dates.

If you want to test if it's within a discrete range then this is what you want :

`where Trunc(SYSDATE) >= FromDate and Trunc(SYSDATE) <= ToDate`

or: `where Trunc(SYSDATE) between FromDate and ToDate`

Note that `trunc(SYSDATE)` suggests that you are using the Oracle database, but if you're using MS SQL you can use `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` to get the date part of the current date.