# Compare two date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we compare Two dates

```
set_up_date = 20-02-18 (in date)
expiry_date = 23-04-20 (in date)

select * 
       BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR('set_up_date','YYYYMMDD')) AND 
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR('expiry_date','YYYYMMDD')) 
  from dual;
```

Comment: Either you need to better explain your query, or show sample data.  This is not answerable right now.

Comment: Did you simply miss the `select ... from ... where` -syntax? `select * 
from dual
where to_date('20170510','YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN to_date('20170509','YYYYMMDD')
  and to_date('20170512','YYYYMMDD');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if current date is between two dates Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398632/check-if-current-date-is-between-two-dates-oracle-sql)

Comment: `'set_up_date'` and `'expiry_date'` are string literals - they are not column names or bind variables.

Comment: what are you expecting???

Answer (score 0):

`'set_up_date'` and `'expiry_date'` are string literals - they are not column names or bind variables. You also need to use the correct syntax for a query which has statements in the order: `SELECT ... FROM ... [WHERE ...] [GROUP BY ...] [ORDER BY ...]`.

So, if you have a table `your_table` with a `your_date_column` column of the `DATE` data type then you can compare it to the two `DATE` variables `set_up_date` and `expiry_date` identified in your question using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table_name
WHERE  your_date_column BETWEEN set_up_date AND expiry_date;
```