# How do i search for a date in a query when sysdate has been used

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sysdate

I have a join query that looks at 2 tables and brings in the dates between a timeframe. I have used sysdate when inserting the data. When I select the data from the table, I am able to see the dates, however, I am not sure how to filter the data by date.

I have tried at the end of my query, but I receive no rows selected:

```
where dateofstart = '04-MAY-20';
```

I have also tried:

```
 where dateofstart = 'date '2020-05-010';
```

And finally, I have tried:

```
 dateofstart between '10-May-20' and '16-May-20';
```

I am using SQL Plus.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398632/check-if-current-date-is-between-two-dates-oracle-sql

Comment: You have several good answers, but let me throw out one side observation.  In your examples above, you sometimes use 2-digit years,and sometimes 4-digit years.  Having spent 2 years busting my butt to help fix Y2K ..... please, please, please _always_ use 4-digit years. No exceptions!

Comment: Thats good info, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used `SYSDATE` *as is*, it is a function that contains date and time, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
06.05.2020 07:20:38

SQL>
```

and is stored as such into your table (I presume that column's datatype is `DATE`).

Therefore, if you searched for `where dateofstart = '04-MAY-20'`, you made two mistakes:

- you are comparing `DATE` datatype column with a string. Yes, `'04-MAY-20'` is a string; it *looks like* date to you and me, but to Oracle it is just a string. Oracle tries to implicitly convert it to date value using NLS settings; sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not. Therefore, you should **always** use dates and not rely on possible conversion success.

  - imagine you compared `dateofstart` to `'01/02/03'`; what is `01`? Is it day (could be)? Month (could be as well)? Year (sure, why not)? But, if you used

    - date literal, which is always in format `yyyy-mm-dd`, e.g. date '2001-03-02', everyone (Oracle included) would know that it is 2nd of March 2001
    - `TO_DATE` function, e.g. `to_date('01/02/03', 'yy/dd/mm')`
- as your column contains date **and** time, you'd get some rows only if `dateofstart` value was stored exactly at midnight at the beginning of that day. If not, either

  - "remove" time component, e.g. `where trunc(dateofstart) = date '2020-05-04'` (which would make use of index (if it existed) on the `dateofstart` column *unusable*, unless you create a function-based index), or
  - use `between`, e.g.

    ```
    where dateofstart between to_date('04.05.2020 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
                          and to_date('04.05.2020 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    ```

---

Your second attempt is wrong (superfluous single quote, `010` (what's that?)).

The third *might* work if Oracle recognized format you used.

---

If the above doesn't help, please, post test case (`create table` and `insert into` several sample records) (edit the original message you wrote) so that we could see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot match exactly the time you inserted, then you should truncate the date:

```
where trunc(dateofstart) = '04-MAY-20';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you NOT to use `between` with dates, particularly in Oracle where they have time components.  The simplest method that is index-safe is:

```
where dateofstart >= date '2020-05-10' and
      dateofstart < date '2020-06-16' + interval '1' day
```

This:

- is readable
- uses standard date literals
- does not require adding a time component to the comparison dates
- works with or without a time component on `dateofstart`
- is index-safe.